# Screenshot of desktop despite lock screen?

Tags: windows, desktop, screenshot, lock-screen

Do you know how to make a screenshot of the Windows ***desktop*** (and ***not*** the lock screen) while lock screen is active?

Technically it must be possible since for screen recording there is [this solution](https://www.apowersoft.com/faq/record-fixed-screen.html) that records a selected window even during an active lockscreen.

It should also be possible to trigger the screenshot programmatically (e.g. via a keyboard shortcut and/or via CMD). Otherwise any solution would do, be it a Windows- or third-party-tool, a registry hack, a script or whatever.

Alternatively, do you know e.g. a third-party lock-screen that doesn't show on screenshots?

Comment: Use a device called a "camera" on a tripod. It will even record a blue-screen--of-death, and a totally inoperative PC.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is not possible. When the lock screen is on the screen that's the only screen that can possibly be recorded.

You misread the ***ApowerREC*** feature description. It most certainly doesn't *"record a selected window even during an active lockscreen."* All it does is locking the recordings region so that it can't move around mid recording.

Comment: It's always interesting to see how "most certain" some people are when in reality all they are is completely wrong.

Comment: Yeah, same with ***must be possible...*** I actually tested it now, and it DOES NOT record anything during lock screen. It freezes what it showed before the lock screen and doesn't change anything on the video recording until the screen is unlocked again.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Yes! you can!

**Long Answer:**

Since at least 2018, you have been able to do it. This is not a new thing!

There is a way to take screenshots of any window even when Windows is locked, by using an AutoIt script. I have been using this method for years now. It is possible that AHK also has a similar way of doing it. Here is the code for the AutoIt script that you can use to take screenshots of any window.

```
; #FUNCTION# ====================================================================================================================
; Author ........: Paul Campbell (PaulIA)
; Modified.......: chimp
;
; modified version of the _ScreenCapture_CaptureWnd() function
; It uses the _WinAPI_PrintWindow() to capture the window
; it should work also with screen locked
;                          -------------
; ===============================================================================================================================
Func _ScreenCapture_CaptureWnd_mod($sFilename, $hWin, $bCursor = True)
    Local $bRet = False

    Local $iSize = WinGetPos($hWin)

    Local $iW = $iSize[2]
    Local $iH = $iSize[3]
    Local $hWnd = _WinAPI_GetDesktopWindow()
    Local $hDDC = _WinAPI_GetDC($hWnd)
    Local $hCDC = _WinAPI_CreateCompatibleDC($hDDC)
    Local $hBMP = _WinAPI_CreateCompatibleBitmap($hDDC, $iW, $iH)

    ; $hCDC Identifies the device context
    ; $hBMP Identifies the object to be selected
    _WinAPI_SelectObject($hCDC, $hBMP)
    _WinAPI_PrintWindow($hWin, $hCDC)

    If $bCursor Then
        Local $aCursor = _WinAPI_GetCursorInfo()
        If Not @error And $aCursor[1] Then
            $bCursor = True ; Cursor info was found.
            Local $hIcon = _WinAPI_CopyIcon($aCursor[2])
            Local $aIcon = _WinAPI_GetIconInfo($hIcon)
            If Not @error Then
                _WinAPI_DeleteObject($aIcon[4]) ; delete bitmap mask return by _WinAPI_GetIconInfo()
                If $aIcon[5] <> 0 Then _WinAPI_DeleteObject($aIcon[5]) ; delete bitmap hbmColor return by _WinAPI_GetIconInfo()
                _WinAPI_DrawIcon($hCDC, $aCursor[3] - $aIcon[2] - $iSize[0], $aCursor[4] - $aIcon[3] - $iSize[1], $hIcon)
            EndIf
            _WinAPI_DestroyIcon($hIcon)
        EndIf
    EndIf

    _WinAPI_ReleaseDC($hWnd, $hDDC)
    _WinAPI_DeleteDC($hCDC)
    If $sFilename = "" Then Return $hBMP

    $bRet = _ScreenCapture_SaveImage($sFilename, $hBMP, True)
    Return SetError(@error, @extended, $bRet)
EndFunc   ;==>_ScreenCapture_CaptureWnd_mod
```

The `_ScreenCapture_CaptureWnd_mod` function only requires the filename and the window handler of the desired app. Examples and discussions can be found in the source link provided at the end of this post.

The source: [Capturing screenshots while computer is locked](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/194120-capturing-screenshots-while-computer-is-locked/?do=findComment&comment=1392304)